# Catching a [Tab] or [Enter] on KeyPress Event

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Is it possible to catch the Enter or Tab key in the KeyPress Event?

I am entering a numeric only value on a comboBox, but once this value has been validated I want the user to be able to either Tab or Enter out of the CB once validated, is this possible from within the keyPress?  Here's my code;

```
Private Sub cbCheckAmount_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles cbCheckAmount.KeyPress
    'Only allowed characters
    Dim allowedChars As String = "0123456789."

    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
        If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
                ' Invalid Character, notify clear and return
                nonNumberEntered = True    'Set to True to 'swallow' the keypress and prevent the TextChanged event from firing.
                MsgBox("Numbers only", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                cbCheckAmount.Text = ""
                cbCheckAmount.Focus()
                cbDollarAmount.Text = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'If shift key was pressed, it's not a number.
    If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Then
        nonNumberEntered = True
        cbCheckAmount.Text = ""
        cbCheckAmount.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub cbCheckAmount_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbCheckAmount.TextChanged
    'Call the function to create a text line out of the numbers
    'Regex to ensure the string contains numbers
    Dim t As ComboBox = sender
    Dim foo As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(cbCheckAmount.Text, foo) Then
        'data is good
        Dim re As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d")
        If re.IsMatch(cbCheckAmount.Text) Then
            If nonNumberEntered = False Then
                Dim newNum = cbCheckAmount.Text.Trim
                'If there are any leading weird . in the string
                newNum = newNum.TrimStart(".")
                Dim newStr As String
                'Build the array
                Dim newDec As String() = newNum.Split(New Char() {"."c})
                If newNum.Contains(".") Then
                    newStr = NumberToText(newDec(0))
                    cbDollarAmount.Text = newStr & " Dollars and " & newDec(1) & "/100 "
                Else
                    newStr = NumberToText(newDec(0))
                    cbDollarAmount.Text = newStr & " Dollars and 00/100 "
                End If

            End If
        End If
    Else
        'data is bad
        nonNumberEntered = False
        cbCheckAmount.Text = ""
        cbCheckAmount.Focus()
        cbDollarAmount.Text = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

I'm using VB 2015

Comment: it already works that way, you don't want KeyPress to fire.  Tab moves the focus and Enter operates the form's default button as configured by the Form.AcceptButton property.  Use the control's Validating event to prevent a focus change when the input is invalid.

Comment: I don't want to fire the AcceptButton at this time, I have other Form Fields to enter data into.  The cbCheckAmount is tabStop 3 of 4.  Which is why I need to allow the user to Tab or Enter out of the field and into the next tabStop.

Answer (score 1):

Stop and listen. The problem you're trying to solve doesn't exist. Just do it properly in the first place. Handle the `Validating` event of each control and do your validation there. If validation fails, set `e.Cancel` to `True` and the control will retain focus. In the `Click` event handler of your OK `Button` or whatever, call the `ValidateChildren` method and that will raise the `Validating` event on every control, even if it never received focus. If any controls fail validation, `ValidateChildren` returns `False` and you know not to try to use the data.  E.g.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    Dim value = TextBox1.Text.Trim()

    'Data is optional but must be numeric if provided.
    If value <> String.Empty AndAlso Not Double.TryParse(value, Nothing) Then
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
        TextBox1.HideSelection = False

        MessageBox.Show("If data is provided, it must be numeric", "Invalid Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        TextBox1.HideSelection = True
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Validating
    'Data is required.
    If TextBox2.Text.Trim() = String.Empty Then
        TextBox2.SelectAll()
        TextBox2.HideSelection = False

        MessageBox.Show("Data must be provided", "Invalid Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        TextBox2.HideSelection = True
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ValidateChildren() Then
        'The data has passed validation so it is safe to use it.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @jmcilhinhey  Nice try, but no.  If you would look at my code you would have been able to see that I am calling a sub on each valid TextChanged, what I want to do is allow the user to Enter or Tab out of the control in the KeyPress event.  I do not want to validate on a button, in fact the validation of my code is done, just need the Tab & Enter to pass to next control.

Comment: You're trying to solve a problem that you created.  If you did it properly in the first place then you wouldn't have this problem to solve.  It's your prerogative to do it wrong, of course, but I'll not spend more time on problems of your own making.

Comment: If you would like to see the entire project, I uploaded it to here; [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7mny2k3ae1fual/CheckPrint.zip?dl=0[/link]  I am using VS2015 and am stuck with getting the user to <Tab> or <Enter> out of the cbCheckAmount properly.  I have spent hours trying to solve this issue, I even tried a PreviewKeyDown and KeyDown event.  I can raise a MsgBox on KeyDown for Tab or Return, but it just will not leave cbCheckAmount populated and SetFocus to the next control.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly isnt what you want just

```
 If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Return) or e.KeyChar = Keys.Tab Then
        ''somethign something''
 End If
```

Comment: This didn't work, threw an error;

Operator '=' is not defined for 'char' or 'keys'

But this is close;

 If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Return) Or e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Tab) Then
            MsgBox("Return or Tab pressed")
        End If

However, it's only catching the Return key and not the Tab key, I think something in my KeyPress is not allowing it to perform the "move to next TabStop"